# Possible corrupted userprofile

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, 64-bit

I think my user profile is corrupted. When I log in, my desktop goes black and all my icons on desktop and shortcuts on the taskbar are gone.

Did system restore several times, but I don't think it repairs these kind of things, or does it?

I found an article at microsoft site how to repair a corrupted profile. But here is the challange: the drive on which my data resides isn't visible.

In the past when I installed windows 7 x64, I did a "conjuction" (forgot how it's called) which is basically create a partition to make windows store your data there in case windows/harddisk crashes as a result losing everything.

So my data is stored on J:\ partition/drive (not sure which it is, as I did it like 3 years ago). But windows will look for my profile in C:\Users (IIRC) while its actually on J:.

But that drives keeps dissapearing and makes everything I have on desktop etc gone and makes the desktop go black.

This happens in safe mode as well. If I do a restore, I can login and use my profile for a few minutes (tops 10) and than everything is 'gone' again.

To sum up a few symptomes:
- skype logs off with disk IO error (logical because the J drive is suddenly gone);
- windows explorer crashes, tries to restart but crashes again and again and again;
- if you're lucky you have a 'temp' profile and gives you access to 'computer' via windows menu;

Not sure if it's a corrupted profile as my drive/partition is gone in 'computer' explorer window.

Anyone having a clue what's going on with my machine? I doubt it's a virus or something.

Comment: Why do you doubt it is a virus or something?

Comment: Because it was a hardware failure which I just found it. And you'd say I'd get a +1 instead of a -1. For those who suffer similiar problems, it seems that my 3rd drive wasn't getting sufficient power. Cleaned pc a few weeks ago, and I think I may have touched it a little and experiencing the result of it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common pattern with drives of any type, and it indicates a hardware problem--they just randomly seem to disconnect/unmount themselves, especially during heavy read/write operations (which logging on would require).  I don't think your user profile is necessarily corrupted in this case, at least not as the root cause of the issue. What you're describing is pretty much the same thing you'd expect to see if someone had just unplugged the USB drive your profile was stored on in the middle of what you were doing.

This may be a problem with literally anything between your drive and your computer, from the various interconnect chips to the cords and sockets as well as the driver.  You also can't rule out RF interference as well, so keep your cords away from anything very electrically active, like your PSU if you can.  The chips in your external enclosure may be shutting down or even powering off, causing Windows to think that it was unplugged, or there may be so much noise on the lines that Windows just marks the device as disconnected.

While there's no way to rule out hardware as the root cause, there are several ways to pinpoint them.

First option is to open the event viewer, which is under the Administrative Tools section on your start menu, or you can run it by going to start>run and typing in "eventvwr.msc."  Once there, on the left-hand column click Windows Logs>System.  Then, on the right-hand column, click "Filter Current Log..." and select "Disk" as the event source.  Look especially for events with the IDs 7, 11, and 57.

Secondly, you may want to check your hard drive's SMART status if the disk supports it.  [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/) is a good tool for that.

It's the nature of any kind of information storage system that failures could happen at any time. It's very important to diversify your risk, keeping multiple backups, some of them offsite, of anything you don't want to lose.

Comment: You're right, it was a hardware failure. It just hit me right after I asked the question that this might be a possibility. Not sure who down voted you though, but it sure as hell wasn't me. I'd say some punk who's pissed off because all holidays are over now.

Comment: @Quoter - I don't find answers that start with "I would guess" particularly helpful.